# Tick correct checkbox if 'checked' within the database

Tags: c#, .net, database, checkbox

I am using c# .net.

Thanks in advance for any help.

I have searched the web, but don't think I am using the right words, as nothing being returned is really helping.

I have a 'edit' section within my web-form which allows the user to tick (using a checklist) certain information.

For example:

•   Receive newsletters
•   Receive phone calls etc

The checklist is populated from a database table called Requirements.

When the user ticks a certain checkbox this information should be stored within another table userRequirement.

I can display all the requirements (from Requirements) by looping through and adding another item:

```
            foreach (tblRequirement singleRequirement in viewAllRequirement)
            {
                requirementCheckBoxList.Items.Add(new ListItem(singleRequirement.requirementName,singleRequirement.rrequirementID.ToString(),true));
            }
```

However how do I then loop through the userRequirement and automatical tick the right checkboxes?

For Example:

- User selects ‘Receive Newsletters’
  checkbox and presses the ‘Update’
  button.
- This is then stored within
  the userRequirement table along with
  the users ID
- If the user wants to
  edit their details again, they can
  do. They are taken to the ‘edit’
  page. Here the ‘Receive Newslettlers’
  should already be selected.

Should I be using a if statement? If so can anyone help by providing an example?

Thanks

Clare

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through all the items in the CheckBoxList using a foreach loop like so:

```
foreach (ListItem item in requirementCheckBoxLis.Items)
{
    item.Selected = true; // This sets the item to be Checked
}
```

You can then set whether an item is checked by setting its Selected property to true. Does that help any?

Answer (score 0):

In your loop, you can select the proper items as they're being entered into the CheckBoxList. Might look something like this (I don't know how your tblRequirement object works):

```
        foreach (tblRequirement singleRequirement in viewAllRequirement)
        {
            ListItem newItem = new ListItem(singleRequirement.requirementName,singleRequirement.rrequirementID.ToString(),true));

            //If item should be checked
            if(singleRequirement.Checked)
                newItem.Selected = true;

            requirementCheckBoxList.Items.Add(newItem);
        }
```